# Surge protection not working on a home projector

Tags: ups, surge-protection

I have a problem with power supply and no idea of how to solve it.

The whole system consists of a projector, an AV receiver, a subwoofer and a PS4. Around 800W. Early when I just got the projector it looked for a while that all was fine and dandy, but later some power disturbances started happening.

So exactly what happens is, while playing or watching movies or whatever the whole screen suddenly displays white noise and the sound disappears. this is happening just for a split second, then i see the projector screen looking for a source also for a second or so and then everything starts working again. The PS4 doesn't restart, the game seems to be continuing while this happens. Sometimes there isn't even a white noise seen, just black screen in which projector is looking for source, quickly finds it again and the display is back again.

I have noticed that around 80% of the time this is happening because of other electric triggers, for example switching on the lights in a different room or switching the cooker on and off and similar, so i'm just thinking the rest of the cases are reactions as well, i just don't know to what exactly.

So I bought a surge protective extension cord and plugged everything in it with no luck. To be on the safe side I tried different circuits around the house - the problem still persisted.

Finally with no more ideas of what to try I decided to go for the big guns and got myself an UPS with the capacity of around 1200W as recommended by one quite competent friend. We were convinced this would fix the problem. It didn't.

So my question is, does anyone have any idea of what could actually be happening here? Also, does it matter that I use an extension cord to plug all the devices to the cord and then this whole system connects to the UPS via the cord as opposed to plugging each device into a separate port? The load indicator shows that the UPS isn’t overloaded.

Comment: We do engineering here, not hand waving.  And -1 for the wall of text.  Also, what's a "PS4"?

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Yes, Olin, we do engineering here and the guy doesn't hand-wave, he states the problem - and his question - very clearly.  He even goes on in great detail to describe his system and what he's done to try to correct the problem on his own, which is admirable and should be responded to, positively,  with engineering help instead of with the  gratuitous slap in the face you seem to be so fond of.

Comment: @EMFi: This post is too painful to read completely, so I can't tell what is being asked.  There is the Great Wall of Text without any formatting or consideration for what it's like to read it.  Then he mentions a "PS4" like we're all just supposed to know what that is.  I did read a few sentences beyond that, but then ran into more thumbing his nose at us.  He couldn't even be bothered to capitalize the first letter in a sentence, then the word "I".  He doesn't take this seriously, so there's no reason I should.  I thought to myself *Screw this*, downvoted, voted to close, and moved on.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Your lack of parsing skills isn't the OP's fault, and while you go to great pains to criticize others' use of the language, you also take great pains to thumb your nose at everyone here by bull-headedly refusing to use the a/an convention properly.  A small point, perhaps, but it does go to show that you're willing to annoy in order to get attention.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not surges, but rather dips in voltage caused by the other loads. A surge protector or an UPS will do nothing for those. Except, of course, if the dip is low enough to convince the UPS that power has failed, in which case, it will start up.

It seems that your projector is particularly sensitive to these dips, and it's going through a reset/startup sequence when they occur. Normally, the filter capacitors inside its power supply would contain enough energy to "ride through" short dropouts and dips. It's possible that the capacitors in yours have aged to the point where their capacity is severely reduced.

The fix would be to replace the capacitors — or the entire power supply, if it is a module. The alternative would be to get an AC voltage regulator, but these are not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet it's the extension cord.

Since your whole system is being powered through a single extension cord, it's acting like a resistance in series with an inductor, both of which are in series with your system, and when your system asks for a lot of current momentarily, the extension cord's impedance causes a large voltage drop across it [the extension cord]  which causes a momentary brownout at your system which is enough to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Not all receptacles on a UPS are powered. Some are just surge-protected. So make sure you plugged into the right ones. Also, I would try to put the UPS right behind the equipment instead of having an extension cord btw the UPS and the equipment.

If that's not the issue, you'd want to look at how often this happens. If it happens fairly often, you can try just unplugging one of the devices at a time and let the rest of the system run and see when it stops happening.

All that being said so you have have some things to try, my gut feel based on what you've said so far is that there's a problem with the AV receiver honestly.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want good surge protection , buy and install, a HEPD80 available on amazon.  Have an electrician install it.   It will protect all your major appliances as well, to include the air conditioner.   You don't want HVAC problems, believe me.  Also check your ground throughout your house and at the main ckt breaker power panel.